# Converting a string into date time

Tags: python, string, datetime, iso8601, strptime

I have the following date in python, as a string which I want to convert to datetime

I tried using strptime function, but due to the format with decimals and a marginal value, it keeps failing. Any idea on how to convert it?
The date string structure is like this example:
`2022-02-08 17:12:35.667000+00:00`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Comment: Did you forget to post your code? It would help if we could see the format specifier you're using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dateutil` module has something just for this. You can use its parser to create a datetime object from a string like this.

```
from dateutil import parser

date_obj = parser.parse("2022-02-08 17:12:35.667000+00:00")
```

**EDIT:**

I don't believe that this is a default python library, so you can type this code into the terminal  to install it with pip: `pip install python-dateutil`

Comment: It's iso format, if you must use dateutil, at least use parser.isoparse